# Django - how to get upload_to directory related to another field

Tags: python, django, database, models

I think the code speaks for itself. I have 2 models - Food and Category and I want to save the food images to a folder that has the same name as the category of the food. I was thinking that I could possibly override the save method but I can't figure out how to make it work. Any ideas?

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete='CASCADE')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='{}'.format(category.name))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Does food instance receive the Category before receiving the image? if it is the case, it's quite easy to do with a @deconstructible class

Comment: obviously, food instance receives the Category before or at the same time, I did not see the parameters in ForeignKey. you can proceed with the answer of @T.Tokic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django documentation says that **upload_to** may also be a callable, such as a function. You can see more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

For your use-case it should be something like this:

```
def food_path(instance, filename):
    return '{0}/{1}'.format(instance.category.name, filename)

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete='CASCADE')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=food_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```